# location of Ubuntu Mobile image?

Tags: ubuntu-touch

This may be naive, but where is the Ubuntu install file to be flashed onto an Android device? I see no links to that image in the instructions or release notes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the phablet-tools on your desktop? From the install instructions,

> Step 1 - Desktop Setup
>
> The following steps are required on your desktop system that you'll
>   need in order to flash and communicate with the device.
>
> Setup the Touch Developer Preview Tools PPA
>
> The PPA has the tools and dependencies to support Precise, Quantal and
>   Raring. Add the Ubuntu Touch PPA by adding the following custom source
>   list entry to your /etc/apt/sources.list file.
>
> `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools`
>
> Then do the following:
>
> `sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install phablet-tools`
>   `android-tools-adb android-tools-fastboot`

Once you've got that running, then putting your unlocked phone/tablet into fastboot and running

```
phablet-flash -b
```

will select the right image for you and download and install it. The full instructions are at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Install

If you want to get at it later on for whatever reason, the image files will have been placed in your user Downloads/phablet-flash folder